# CKEditor getting the content of the editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to get the content of CKEditor with jQuery and then send it through AJAX....

but the `$(..).val()` or `$(..).html()` does not work and it seems I should use `CKEditor` object.

Any help on how to get the content?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, CKEditor created an iframe and saved the content in it.

However, you can try the following method instead:

```
var content = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
```

Or, you can use a built-in function.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('my-editor');

// Some Event, maybe Ajax
var val = editor.getData();
```

Here is the documentation for that: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData

Good luck!